# C++ std::map::iterator found nothing, yet subscript operator returns reference to mapped value?

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

Probably doing something very dumb, but I can't figure out why `find` doesn't find an element with a key equivalent to `suppID`.

Yet when I pass the subscript operator `suppID`, it returns what a reference to its mapped value (implying it found something, right?).

```
typedef std::map<SuppID, Supplement *> Supplement_t;

Supplement_t::iterator it = supplements.find(suppID);  //it = supplements.end()

cout << "Supplement name: " << supplements[suppID]->getName() << endl; // "Cytogainer"
... // Returns few of many other data members I tested...
```

Comment: Let me guess, `SuppID` is a complex type and you wrote your own `<` for it.

Comment: @Yakk Correct.  That tip lead me to read further and found all the elements need to return false reflexively.  Currently they do not, so I believe that is indeed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing `<` for an associative container it is easy to get it wrong.

The easy way is to write a function or method that returns a tuple, either of references or values or a mixture.  Call if `foo`.

```
friend bool operator<( self const& lhs, self const& rhs ){
  return lhs.foo()<rhs.foo();
}
```

If you write a `<` wrong, you will get simply insane behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `std::map` inserts a default value for new key values that do not exist yet when using the *subscript operator*.

As stated [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at):

> 1) Inserts value_type(key, T()) if the key does not exist. This function is equivalent to return insert(std::make_pair(key, T())).first->second;
>   -key_type must meet the requirements of CopyConstructible.
>   -mapped_type must meet the requirements of CopyConstructible and DefaultConstructible.
>   If an insertion is performed, the mapped value is value-initialized (default-constructed for class types, zero-initialized otherwise) and a reference to it is returned.

Comment: I read as well, but it does not appear that element was constructed using its default constructor.  Hence `Supplement *`'s `getName()` returns `"cytogainer"` instead of `"default protein shake"`.  Very confused.

Comment: @lololololol Well, I can't judge from that narrow sample you give why that happens.